# Contraseña o Correo electrónico incorrecto php

Tags: php, html, sql, login

Cordial Saludo.
Estoy estudiando y practicando PHP. Cree un formulario de login, para que se muestren en la misma página "Bienvenido Usuario" una vez el usuario ingrese sus credenciales.

El usuario ingresa sus credenciales que son correo y contraseña, pero en el momento de ingresar los datos requeridos y correctamente, me arroja el error que cree "Contraseña o Correo electrónico incorrecto". No entiendo hasta el momento el ¿Porqué? del error, si pienso que está bien escrito.

Por eso acudo a ustedes, que tienen experiencia y me guíen.

Adjunto código.

Tanto el html como php se encuentran un mismo archivo que llame login.php

```
<?php
require "php/conex.php";


if (isset($_POST['correo'])) {

    $correo = $_POST['correo'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];
    $clave = hash_hmac('sha512', $password, 'keySecret');
    // Query BD
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE correo = '".$correo."' AND password_user='".$clave."'";
    $r = mysqli_query($conex, $sql);
    $n = mysqli_num_rows($r);
    if ($n==1) {
        echo "Bienvenido";
    } else {
        $error = "Contraseña o Correo electrónico incorrecto.";
    }


}
?>

<h2>Ingresar</h2>

<?php                                                    
                                                        
    if (isset($error)) {
        echo '<div class="alert alert-danger">';
        echo '<strong>* '.$error.'</strong>';
        echo '</div>';
    }
?>
<form action="login.php" method="post" class="login">

    <p class="before-login-text">¡Bienvenido de nuevo! Inicia sesión.</p>

    <p class="form-row form-row-wide">
        <label for="username">Ingresa dirección de correo electrónico<span class="required">*</span></label>
        <input type="email" class="input-text" name="correo" id="correo"
            value="<?php if(isset($correo)) echo $correo ?>" />
    </p>

    <p class="form-row form-row-wide">
        <label for="password">Ingresa la contraseña<span class="required">*</span></label>
        <input type="password" class="input-text" name="password" id="password" />
    </p>

    <p class="form-row">
        <input class="button" type="submit" value="Ingresar" name="login">
        <label for="rememberme" class="inline"><input name="rememberme" type="checkbox" id="rememberme"
                value="forever" /> Recordar</label>
    </p>

    <p class="form-row">
        <a href="recuperar-password.php" class="btn btn-outline-success">¿Olvidó la contraseña?</a>
        <a href="mi-cuenta.php" class="btn btn-outline-success">¿No tienes cuenta?</a>
    </p>

</form>
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Agradezco de antemano a la persona que me ayude o explique el fallo que tengo.

Comment: Imprime el resultado del metodo **hash_hmac** y compara el valor devuelto sea el mismo que en tu BD, supongo que ahí se encuentra el problema.

Comment: Gracias, lo voy hacer.

Answer (score 0):

He replicado tu código. Pero yo cambié **$clave** y use el valor de **$password**

```
$conex = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root','','pruebas');
if (isset($_POST['correo'])) {

    $correo = $_POST['correo'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];
    echo '<br>'.$clave = hash_hmac('sha512', $password, 'keySecret');
    // Query BD
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM login WHERE mail = '".$correo."' AND psw ='".$password."'";
    $r = mysqli_query($conex, $sql);
    echo '<br>'.$n = mysqli_num_rows($r);
    if ($n==1) {
        echo '<br>'."Bienvenido";
    } else {
        $error = "Contraseña o Correo electrónico incorrecto.";
    }
}
// Resultado del navegador 
08692f76283f7...
1
Bienvenido
```

Lo que debes hacer es depurar tu código desde un inicio. Yo lo haría así:

- Verificar que mi conexión funciona perfectamente
- Verificar que el hash creado para el Password es correcto
- El **keySecret** de `hash_hmac()` debe ser seteado también, como se da cuenta tu código de cual es el **keySecret**??

Para mi, que la ultima opción es la de tu problema.

Comment: Tienes razón, la última opción deberia ser el error. Gracias.

Comment: Cuando lo compruebes nos retroalimentas tu solución...

Comment: @OCHOA, observando un poco tu respuesta no veo en que momento utilizas la variable $clave que es la que codifica el password, en la sentencia sql lo estas haciendo directamente con el dato que se recibe.

Comment: @AntonioGalicia, pero no necesita observar el código, en la primera frase lo pongo en negrita. Justo por eso llegué a la conclusión de que o bien es la conexión o el hash, al final yo me decanto por el hash. Lo que no hice fue generar el pass porque desconozco como lo ha generado el OP cuando hace el insert o registro de dicho usuario...

Comment: Les comento que la solución fue agrandar la longitud de caracteres en la BD, lo tenia con 50, lo pase a 200. Hice la prueba y funciono, realice varias pruebas eliminando el registro en la BD y siguío funcionando, es decir el usuario se loguea con éxito. No se a que se deba. Agradezco una explicación como tambien a la solución que cada uno planteo o una página donde expliquen un poco más sobre este caso para futuro(si lo desean hacer). Gracias a los dos.

Comment: Se debe a lo que hiciste, lo mas probable es que cuando hacías el insert, tu hash se cortaba a los 50 caracteres, por ende cuando vuelves a verificar el password nunca harían match. Te aconsejo que definas una longitud exacta para tu pass (64 o 128 es ideal), y cuando uses un método para hacer dicho hash definas la misma longitud de tu DB, eso es más seguridad para tu sistema...